# Why does Ubuntu trigger thermal protection shutdowns on my Dell laptop?

Tags: 12.04, laptop, dell, ati

I have been using Windows (Vista and 7) for quite some time on my DELL Studio 1555 and I have never experienced overheating problems (even when rendering videos etc.) but as soon as I turn on my laptop with Ubuntu, the fan starts spinning at full speed and the temperature starts rising steadily. The temperature rises to a point where the laptop shuts down due to too much heat!

Here are some additional details:
Laptop model: DELL STUDIO 1555
BIOS version: A13 (latest, as per DELL website)
Graphic card: ATI Radeon HD 4570

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 12.04 and have upgraded and updated everything, and the problem still persists.

This seems to be a common problem with many DELL laptops but I have not been able to find a proper solution...

Comment: Sagar, this is a common occurrence in *all* laptops, and has to do with a flaw in systems with powerful graphics cards, which happens in Dells.  There is no solution, except maybe a cooling pad, or not having the laptop flush against the work surface (so the fans can still operate).  As well, this is also a limitation in the temperature regulation within the OS (which Windows and Dell drivers for Windows take into account)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is absence of proprietary graphics drivers. See if you have `xorg.conf` in `/etc/X11`. Most likely it would be either absent or with improper configuration.

**CHECK PRESENT TEMPERATURE:**

First install lm-sensors using `sudo apt-get install lm-sensors`

Then run `sudo sensors-detect` and say YES to all the options.

Now, run `sensors` and see how the temperatures are.

**INSTALL PROPRIETARY GRAPHIC DRIVERS:**

After this, install the proprietary Radeon drivers using "Additional Drivers" or jockey-gtk from Unity Dash.

Then run  `sudo aticonfig --initial` to configure `xorg.conf` properly.

**CHECK TEMPERATURE AGAIN:**

Now, run `sensors` again and see if there is any difference in temperature.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the exact DELL Studio laptop and my laptop runs cooler in Ubuntu than Windows 7.

I did following things to bring the system temperature significantly.

1. Install proprietary graphics driver throught jockey-gtk. Search for jockey in unity menu.
2. Install tlp to control HDD and WIFI power consumption. ( It's not necessary but significantly reduced the palm rest temperature )